# What happens if an exception is triggered from code to redefine operators in c#?

Tags: c#, exception

What would happens if an exception is triggered from code to redefine operators in c#?

Comment: there would be an exception...?

Answer (score 4):

I think your question is "will my operator be redefined ?".

Yes it will. The redefinition of the operator is done at compile time. So if the code compiles, the operator is redefined.

Now if that operator throws an exception, it will be thrown when the operator is called at runtime, like any other exception.

Answer (score 1):

Overloaded operators are normal static methods that happen to have a special name (eg, `op_Multiply`).

Their exceptions work just like other exceptions.